# Reference should outlive closure parameter

Tags: rust

So I've got the following structs

```rust
struct Item;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Resource<'a> {
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a> Resource<'a> {
    // Note: item has to be borrowed for 'a
    fn do_nothing(&mut self, item: &'a Item) {
        let _ = item;
    }
}

struct Context<'a> {
    resource: Resource<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Context<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { resource: Resource::default() }
    }

    fn do_something(&mut self, item: &'a Item) {
        self.resource.do_nothing(item);
    }
}
```

And the following function that uses those sturcts.

```rust
fn do_stuff<F>(callback: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(Context),
{
    let ctx = Context::new();
    (callback)(ctx);
}
```

When I try using this in the following manner

```rust
fn main() {
    let item = Item;

    do_stuff(|mut ctx| {
        ctx.do_something(&item);
    });
}
```

It gives the following compiler error:

```
error[E0597]: `item` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:40:27
   |
39 |     do_stuff(|mut ctx| {
   |              --------- value captured here
40 |         ctx.do_something(&item);
   |         ------------------^^^^-
   |         |                 |
   |         |                 borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `item` is borrowed for `'static`
41 |     });
42 | }
   | - `item` dropped here while still borrowed
```

However, with my limited understanding of rust lifetimes, I'm not sure how to fix it. Item should outlive `ctx` as `ctx` only lives as long as `do_stuff`(?). Is there a way to tell the compiler that `item` lives longer then `ctx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I highly recommend when dealing with lifetimes is to attempt to desugar lifetime elision as much as possible. The issue here actually happens in your definition of `do_stuff`:

```
fn do_stuff<F>(callback: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(Context),
{
    let ctx = Context::new();
    (callback)(ctx);
}
```

which desugars to:

```
fn do_stuff<F>(callback: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(Context<'static>),
{
    let ctx = Context::new();
    callback(ctx);
}
```

That `'static` is what is causing the error. If you make the function generic over lifetime `'a` the error goes away:

```
fn do_stuff<'a, F>(callback: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(Context<'a>),
{
    let ctx = Context::new();
    callback(ctx);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c9be1f25d405e468470225b74352070)

Comment: `FnOnce(Context)` does *not* desugar into `FnOnce(Context<'static>)` but rather `for<'a> FnOnce(Context<'a>)`. This has the same error, and the link to `'static` that the error complains about is because the `callback` can be called with a `Context` of *any* lifetime and the only reference that can satisfy *any* lifetime is `'static`. The solution is correct though.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=de1486bb201195a9be870b0aedb5629a) that demonstrates that `ctx` is not `Context<'static>` cuz it'd work if it were.

Comment: Yeah I've tried to explain it that way in plain terms, but I'm at a loss for words. Feel free to edit the answer with a better explanation, or present your own answer.